# HTML/JavaScript Music Player That Can Be Called With an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, iframe

I was wondering If anyone knows of a music player Where I can put the code in a separate part of the app and then load it up through an iframe. For example:

```
%iframe{:frameborder => "0", :scrolling => "no", :src => "/music/player/file.html?file=#{@song.mp3}"}
```

So far I've tried amazing audio player but it's not allowing me to select the mp3 file (you can only choose the ten songs you pick when you created the player). I've seen a few JavaScript libraries that have the music player but so far nothing I've seen can be implemented within an iframe.

It would be even better if it is a rails gem (easiest to implement within the app). Thank you so much.

Comment: [Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I've edited it to talk about what I did before asking the question.